# iterator with increasing numbers

Tags: java

How do I write iterator that will as parameter get length of number and for next() give number of that length but with digits in increasing digits (diff between digits is exactly 1)? Digits are from 1 to 9.

For example if length is 3.

```
DecIterator iter=new DecIterator(3);
iter.next(); //123
iter.next(); //234
iter.next(); //345
```

and so on.

I have no idea how to write that next(). Should I use String and than go through array of char and than add all of them and parse it back to Integer? That doesnt seem to be nice way of doing this.

Comment: Note that the leading zero in `012` is superfluous, and for the most part isn't really there in a Java integer.

Comment: Use string and concatenate numbers after you increment them.

Comment: I edited the question it doesnt mattr to me

Comment: [StringBuilder append int](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(int))

Comment: I know that is my idea @ScaryWombat

Comment: @Goion but how to know that next from 123 should be 234? Where should i save that previous value and so on

Comment: As a member variable

Comment: Question text says *"decreasing"*, but the examples are all *increasing* values. Which is it?

Comment: My mistake @Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```
public final class DecIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private final int length;
    private int firstDigit = 1;

    public DecIterator(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (this.firstDigit + this.length <= 10);
    }
    @Override
    public Integer next() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (! hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
            value = value * 10 + this.firstDigit + i;
        this.firstDigit++;
        return value;
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
DecIterator iter = new DecIterator(3);
while (iter.hasNext())
    System.out.println(iter.next());
```

*Output*

```
123
234
345
456
567
678
789
```